# "RepeatForUnit" item missing in Calendar entry?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am accessing RepeatForUnit to manage "Repeats" in Lotus Notes.

String RepeatForUnit  = (string)((object[])docCalendarDoc.GetItemValue("RepeatForUnit"))[0];

Initially i was getting "D" for Daily event, "W" for Weekly and "Y" for Yearly.

But now properties field not showing any of this value even after adding Repeat in calendar.It is not visible in Properties list of Lotus Notes Calendar and showing "" (black entry) for above code.

I am not getting why this is happening.Can anybody help me out in this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the logic, but Notes sometimes does not include the RepeatUnit, RepeatForUnit, etc fields and insteads treats the repeating calendar entry as a "custom" repeat, which uses only the "RepeatInstanceDates" item (which is a multi-values date datatype). Depending on what your code is doing, perhaps it can also check this item.

A listing of the "repeating calendar entry" - related items can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=463&context=SSKTMJ&dc=DB560&dc=DB520&uid=swg21229486&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8&lang=en&rss=ct463lotus).