# Recurrance Calendar Issue in Lotus Notes

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I am creating a Daily Reccurrance pattern in calendar items. But there is a issue as before clicking "save and Send Invitations" button, but in the Document Properties field i am able to view the RepeatForUnit and based on its value i am identifying the Reccurrance type like (D: for daily, W: for Weekly, M: for montlhy etc).

But, After clicking on the "save and Send Invitations" button, the Recurrance is getting saved but after that, i am unable to get the RepeatForUnit field in Document Properties.

Kindly help me, how to identify the Reccurrance type and the related fields.

Note: I am using Domino.dll using C#.

Comment: I don't get the relation to c#. Any help?

Comment: I am using Domino.dll and using C# to access nsf file .

Comment: Can you share some of your code to help illustrate the issue?

Comment: `and`? really? you tagged your question `and`?

Answer (score 0):

Preeti (who asked this question) also asked a very similar question here:
["RepeatForUnit" item missing in Calendar entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504370)

I've experienced the same problem with a Java app: the RepeatForUnit, RepeatUntil, RepeatHow, and other "repeat" fields are not present when I inspect the calendar document.

The answer to the linked question is probably correct: Notes is treating the entry as a custom repeating entry so the "repeat" fields are not present. That's a bummer because I want to use the "repeat" fields to build a corresponding iCal entry.